# How to find data, based on column name and values on the Other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets.
Sheet1, Sheet2

The structure of Sheet1:

[image]

The structure of Sheet2:

[image]

I am trying to do filter data on the sheet1 based on the input of sheet2. The process of filter:

1. User will Open the workbook.
2. He will select the sheet2.
3. He will type the name of the column in the column name field which is existed on the sheet1. In case if the column name does not exist on the sheet1, it will pop up the error message that the column does not exist or your spelling is wrong.
4. Then he will put the value which he wants to filter in that column, and press filter button to active the filter on the sheet1.

I am trying following code but it does not work.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim SelRange As Range
    Dim ColNum As Integer
    
    Dim CWS As Worksheet, TmpWS As Worksheet
    
    'Find the column number where the column header is
    Set CWS = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ColNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("CRATIME", CWS.Rows(1), 0)
    'Set the column range to work with
    Set SelRange = CWS.Columns(ColNum)
    'Add a worksheet to put '1' onto the clipboard, ensures no issues on activesheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set TmpWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        With TmpWS
            .Cells(1, 1) = 1
            .Cells(1, 1).Copy
        End With
        'Select none blank cells using special cells...much faster than looping through all cells
        Set SelRange = SelRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
        SelRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlMultiply
        TmpWS.Delete
        CWS.Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ColNum.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Use [FILTER()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function) function instead of `VBA`.

Comment: If a user is not familiar with Excel Functions, they may cause problems with your worksheet if they try to change the FILTER() function . You don't have to make the user go to `Sheet 2` to input the filter column and value. If you want to allow your users to be able to select the filter column and value on the worksheet, you can either use two `InputBoxes` so your user can select the filter column and value, and assign variables to the filter column and value . Or you can use a `UserForm` (the preferred method). You could use a button on the worksheet to run the macro  or start the `UserForm`

Comment: Thanks.  any other suggestion, please